# In mvc String is null or empty is not check the null values

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, isnullorempty

I have `Industry` type in my database. When it is null, it is showing an error like:

**"Nullable object must have a value."**

I want my value to display empty when it is null too.

**This is my code:**

```
<p>
    <strong>Industry Type:</strong>
    <%: Model.GetIndustry(Model.IndustryId.Value).Name%>
</p>
```

Anyone have an idea? Please help me...

Comment: use `Model.IndustryId.HasValue` to check if nullable object has value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is similar to "von v"'s answer, but I think the error of "Nullable object must have a value." can be from IndustryId since is nullable, so it is good to check for that first:

```
 <p>
    <strong>Industry Type:</strong>
    <%:if(Model.IndustryId.HasValue)
    {
      var idustry =  Model.GetIndustry(Model.IndustryId.Value);
      if(industry!= null)
        industry.Name
    }
    else
    {
    ""
    }
%>        
</p>
```

In my view it is good to do this

```
Model.GetIndustry()
```

in Back end, like controller, and then return the industry by viewstate,
like checking in the:

```
string industryName = "";
     if(Industry.IndustryId.HasValue){
    var industry = YourClass.GetIndustry(Industry.IndustryId.Value);
    industryName = industry!= null ? Industry.Name : "" ;
}
ViewBag.IndustryName= industryName;
```

and then use your ViewBag in view like this:

```
<p>
    <strong>Industry Type:</strong>
    <%: ViewBag.IndustryName %>
</p>
```

It is good to separate the checking from view and do the logics in code.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Have you tried using `GetValueOrDefault`? You can use that on nullable fields and it's a shorthand to the if-else shorthand. So if you want to do a `if (variable.HasValue ? variable.Value : some_value)` you can do it like this instead `variable.GetValueOrDefault(some_value)`. You can get creative with it.

Comment: Thanks von v. But if the e YourClass.GetIndustry(Industry.IndustryId.GetValueOrDefault(0))    we call the method of GetIndustry for nothing!? Am I right?

Comment: Like I said you can get creative with it. In the `GetIndustry` method, it can accept a non-existing id, so the view can actually pass in zero or negative numbers. That means so you still have to sanitize the `id` parameter for in `GetIndustry`. So why have additional logic of testing for nullability when you can just pass zero for nulls. Then let the `GetIndustry` sanitize it, as like I've mentioned, it should do it anyway.

Comment: Fair enough, But remember, in case of testing, you still need to test for the zero value call inside of GetIndustry()! and also another test for the YourClass.GetIndustry() when its sending zero or the value!

Comment: I think that's what I just said. I don't get that `YourClass.GetIndustry()` though.

Answer (score 0):

Check that an industry is returned first then write the name if there's any

```
<%
  var industry = Model.GetIndustry(Model.IndustryId.Value);
%>

<%: industry == null ? "" : industry.Name %>
```

Is `IndustryId` nullable? Then you can do this

```
<%
    var industry = Model.GetIndustry(Model.IndustryId.GetValueOrDefault(0));
%>
```

and in the `GetIndustry` method, you can just return `null` if the id is zero.

```
public Industry GetIndustry(int id) {
    if (id==0) return null;
    // else do your stuff here and return a valid industry
}
```

Answer (score 0):

string can accept null or empty value, why don't you try `string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.IndustryId.Value)`

this is pretty self explanatory. in your controller,

```
  string yourValue = string.empty;
  yourValue = Model.GetIndustry(Model.IndustryId.Value).Name;

  if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(yourValue))
  {
     //display your result here!
  }

  ViewBag.IndustryValue = yourValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try something along the lines of

```
<p>
    <strong>Industry Type:</strong>
    <%: Model.IndustryId.HasValue ? Model.GetIndustry(Model.IndustryId.Value).Name : string.Empty%>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the Problem.

```
 <p>
    <strong>Industry Type:</strong>
    <% if (Model.IndustryId.HasValue)
      { %>
     <%: Model.GetIndustry(Model.IndustryId.Value).Name%>

     <%}
      else
      { %>
     <%:Model.IndustryId==null ? "": Model.GetIndustry(Model.IndustryId.Value).Name %>
     <%} %>
    </p>
```